# Estimate the expected value and SD of a random variable from a dependent random variable with those parameters known

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ and we know its expected value $E[X]$ and standard deviation $\sigma_X$. We also have a law $f$ that connects $X$ with another parameter $Y$, i.e. $f(X)=Y$. In such general setting is it possible to estimate the standard deviation of $Y$? Could it be as simple as $\sigma_X=f(\sigma_Y)$ and $E[Y] = f(E(X))$?

**Example #1 (folding of a sort)**. We are given a random point on plane with expected value $(0,0)$, standard deviation of the $x$-coordinate $\sigma_x$ and standard deviation of the $y$-coordinate $\sigma_y$. What is the expected value of the polar radius of this point and its standard deviation?

In this example the connecting law is $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

**Example #2 (residual of the surface coordinates)**. We are given a point $p$ on a plane $xOy$ with coordinates $(0,h>0)$. The straight line goes through point $p$ at the random angle $\alpha$ to the coordinate line $Oy$. We know $E[\alpha]$ and $\sigma_\alpha$. This line intersects $Ox$ in the point $(x_0, 0)$. How to find $E[x_0]$ and $\sigma_{x_0}$? Is it $E[x_0]=0$ and $\sigma_{x_0}=h\cdot\tan{\sigma_\alpha}$?

[image]

In this example the connecting law is $f(\alpha)=h\cdot\tan\alpha$. If we consider the coordinates of the point $p=(h,d)$ to be also random, than we'll need to use the law $f(\alpha,\ h,\ d)= h\cdot\tan\alpha+d$.

---

For what its worth, my interest in this mostly lies within the grasp of the problem of determining the residuals of the object coordinates on the photographs obtained via aerial survey, given the drone coordinates (or any other airborne photographic equipment) and surface object coordinates and all corresponding SDs.

Comment: There isn't such a trivial relation between expectations of $X$ and $f(X)$, but you can look up [the law of unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). That may be helpful.